# Get Data from Shopify using JQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I am building an application where I need to fetch data from my Shopify account using Jquery Ajax. I have gone through documents provided by Shopify, but I have not landed to any solution yet because the documentation provided by Shopify does not make any sense. Please provide solution if you guys have any.

Comment: Have you seen this help page of Shopify : https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference    (using the shopify Ajax API) they provide examples

Comment: I have seen but it does not make any sense. Please provide and example if possible.

Comment: What data do you need exactly? What kind of account do you have? Give more details

Comment: I have Shopify account and I want to get list of all customers from using jQuery ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You have this help page : https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#

this url is available :

> GET     /admin/api/2019-04/customers.json

this retrieves a list of customers.
The documentation show you how to :

- Retrieve all customers for a shop
  GET /admin/api/2019-04/customers.json
- Retrieve all customers after a specified ID
  GET /admin/api/2019-04/customers.json?since_id=207119551
- Retrieve all customers changed after a certain date
  GET /admin/api/2019-04/customers.json?updated_at_min=2019-04-17 19:42:24
- Retrieve a list of specific customers
  GET /admin/api/2019-04/customers.json?ids=207119551,1073339460

You just have to do a GET call.

This link show you how do you have to do : https://guide.freecodecamp.org/jquery/jquery-ajax-get-method/

Comment: actually above approach do not works when I  am not logged in my account.

Comment: This is normal, you must have the correct token authentication for this request in the header. Otherwise everyone could see your customers

Comment: would you please share an example. So that I can grasp your point well.

Comment: that's another question about basic authentification with ajax... you can this help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/use-basic-authentication-with-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: Actually this is raising CORS issue. I need need to send ajax requests to Shopify from some other domain not from Shopify itself.